# Set *.exe file properties after upload to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find a way to write "meta" information to EXE files that are uploaded to my IIS/ASP.NET web service. Here's a little bit of background:

- I need to write one arbitary string into the properties

  - It'll be URL that I write as "metadata", if that matters
  - Example: `https://example.com/someFolder/someOtherFolder`
- The files are mainly installers originally created by InnoSetup
- The web server is running IIS 7.5 with ASP.NET on top of Server 2008 R2 (Standard)

**Why am I trying to write this information?**

Ultimately the EXEs are made available to users for download. When the application runs, it needs to know the web URL in order to execute properly. Currently we have a plain text box where the user can input the URL, but that has proven to be error prone (despite prompting/error checking/...)

**Why can't I just write the metadata in the EXE when it's created?**

I could do that, but the EXE could be uploaded to a variety of different servers, each with their own unique URL "metadata". I'm trying to avoid creating a separate build script for each server.

**Why not just create a *.zip file with the *.exe and an extra piece of metadata?**

I suppose I could do that too -- but then the user would have to actually unzip the download so that the real installer could read the metadata. I had something similar to this before and most people never unzipped the full download and that posed its own problems.

So is this even possible? I guess as  a last resort I could use the uploaded EXE to create a new EXE, but I'm trying to avoid doing that (gets into problems with signed EXEs, etc.)

Comment: Does that metadata even persist when the user downloads the file? My gut says not usually. Perhaps a self-extracting zip file would be the best of both worlds?

Comment: Not sure. I know certain files, like `*.mp3` have extended properties that are persisted across downloads. Not sure about *.exe files though

Comment: The MP3 file format just has a chunk of data at the end that can be interpreted as ID3 info. I'm not aware of anything similar for .exe files except for using NTFS metadata, which I'm almost positive wouldn't be persisted (because it exists in the file system, not in the bits of the file itself).

Comment: Just a hint: Changing the exe would also change it's hash code used for verification. So you and user cannot be sure anymore that the code contains no malware.